# Angular, popup menu for each populated row

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Angular 10, I have populated table rows from an array of objects and each row has a **button which toggle a popup menu**, (There are two buttons in the popup menu) and clicking on those buttons will get the row id and will call a new component. All is good and I can take the id for each row. The problem is that I don't know how to have it setup that clicking the row button only show one popup for that selected row which should be displayed next to the row (overlay). right now when I click all popup show.

```
 <table >
    <div *ngFor="let car of car.models">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>{{car.amount)}}</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <div (click)="openPopup()"> <img src="button.png"> </div>

                    <div *ngIf="showPopup"> 
                        <a><div>open page 1</div></a>
                        <a><div>open page 2</div></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </div>
</table>
```

And in the TS file:

```
 openPopup() {
    this.showPopup = !this.showPopup;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since showPopup is a single variable, all rows reference the same value. You could either create a new component for each row, which then encapsulates the value of showPopup or make it a list. The latter is shown in this sample code

```html
<div *ngFor="let car of car.models; let index = index">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>{{car.amount)}}</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <div (click)="openPopup(index)"> <img src="button.png"> 
            </div>

                <div *ngIf="showPopup[index]"> 
                    <a><div>open page 1</div></a>
                    <a><div>open page 2</div></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
     </tr>
</div>
```

```js
showPopup = []
openPopup(index: number) {
    this.showPopup[index] = !this.showPopup[index];
  }
```

Comment: Do you know how I can close other popup if user clicks on a another toggle button (on different row)?

Comment: Well, whenever opening a new popup, you could first iterate over the array and set all items to false, thus closing the corresponding popups

Comment: I am not sure this should be a new question or not, but I have one thing to change on each row and that is an icon on the row that shows "+" and "-" to indicate the open popup. I tried using index again for it, but it is not working. I am using an image for each so I need to only switch the image on the selected row.

Comment: It would be great, if you made this a new question and included your current code, since it is rather difficult to debug issues without knowing the respective code